# Is it possible to transform audio with neural networks to make it sound like 3d sound

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, python, keras

so the idea is to feed neural network data like

input: mono audio(extracted from existing 3d audio) output: 3d audio

after training it should convert mono audio to 3d sound

do you think it is possible? does it already implemented?(I didn't found)

P.S
it should sound like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVH_y0rOyGM

not like usual 3d youtube.com/watch?v=QFaSIti5_d0

Comment: I have not heard of ASMR in the context of a technical sound quality ("high quality 3d sound") but in context of audio content type - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASMR - it involves low sound levels because it involves recording quiet sounds like whispering, and may require accurate noise-free stereo recording to have desired effect for some kinds of source, so may be recorded in high quality for that reason. So could you clarify - are you trying to improve quality on recordings of ASMR content (as per the Wikipedia link), or have some other goal.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong and ASMR is also the name of an audio quality standard? In which case please link to a definition and explain which kinds of content you need to enhance.

Comment: so, the basic idea is to make sound feels natural, and you should hear the position of it
I want to feed my neural network dataset consists of [x, y, monosound] -> 3d sound(supervised learning), the monosound is extract from existing 3d sound

when neural network trained, it should be able to convert 
x, y, monosound -> 3d

Comment: to see difference between regular 3d sound and asmr take a look on this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVH_y0rOyGM&t=53s - asmr
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFaSIti5_d0 - 3d sound
(put on headphones)

Comment: so, the idea is pass mono audio + (x, y, z coordinates) -> get 3d sound, it can be not neural network, any technology, I just want to know, which will be the best to do it

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I do not think you are asking about ASMR at all. Instead, it happens to be the case that ASMR fans like high quality binaural recordings. Please could you update your question to make it clear what you are asking? Use [edit] to make changes

Comment: This is generally done with softwares with static programming. Why do you need a learning algorithm for this?

Comment: could you give an example?